# using awk remove filtered group

Tags: awk

i have an input

```
1   a   0,9
1   b   0,8
1   c   0,1
2   d   0,5
3   e   0,1
3   f   0,7
4   g   0,4
4   h   0,3
4   i   0,2
4   j   0,1
```

using awk i want to remove filtered group
if third column is greater than 0.6 i want to remove other rows which first columns equal.

Desired Output:

```
2   d   0,5
4   g   0,4
4   h   0,3
4   i   0,2
4   j   0,1
```

I have used this, but this dont delete other rows.

```
awk  '($3 < 0.6)'  file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  temp=$3
  sub(/,/,".",temp)
  if(temp>0.6){
    noCount[$1]
  }
  next
}
!($1 in noCount)
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2   d   0,5
4   g   0,4
4   h   0,3
4   i   0,2
4   j   0,1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##This condition will be TRUE when first time is being read.
  temp=$3                    ##Creating temp with 3rd field value here.
  sub(/,/,".",temp)          ##Substituting comma with dot in temp here.
  if(temp>0.6){              ##Checking condition if temp is greater than 0.6 then do following.
    noCount[$1]              ##Creating noCount with index of 1st field.
  }
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!($1 in noCount)             ##If 1st field is NOT present in noCount then print line.
'  Input_file  Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: thanks for your correction. But i want to see '1 c 0,1' and '3 e 0,1'  at output.

Comment: @ersan, Ok please check my updated answer and let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. While there is an undesired value in the 3rd column, I want to delete the other data belonging to the first column of the same row.

Comment: @ersan, Could you please try my edited code and let me know if All is Well now.

Comment: of course. Sorry for my weak language. For example, Third column of first row have unwanted value. Because it has "0,9". First column of first row is "1". After that, i want to delete other rows which has "1" value of First column.

Comment: @ersan, no issues, I think I got it correctly, please do check my updated code and let me know how it goes, this is working fine as per shown samples.